# Relative Position of Words in String in R

Tags: r, regex, position, text-mining

I have the following term documnet matrix and dataframe.

```
tdm <- c('Free', 'New', 'Limited', 'Offer')



Subject                                               Free New Limited Offer                                                    

'Free Free Free! Clear Cover with New Phone',          0   0     0      0
'Offer ! Buy New phone and get earphone at             0   0     0      0
1000. Limited Offer!'
```

I want to derive the following dataframe as the output

```
Subject                                              Free  New Limited Offer    
'Free Free Free! Clear Cover with New Phone',        1,2,3  8   NA     NA
Offer ! Buy New phone and get earphone at  1000.      NA    3   12      1,13
Limited Offer!'
```

I tried the following code and got a result but this only gives me the position of the word along a string. I need the position of the words as in Hell0 - 1 new- 2.

```
for(i in 1:length(tdm))
{    word.locations <- 
gsub(")","",gsub("c(","",unlist(paste(gregexpr(pattern 
= tdm[i], DF$Subject))), fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)
  df <- cbind(DF,word.locations)
  }
  colnames(DF) <- c("text", word)
```

I request someone to help.

Comment: Your column is fixed?

Comment: @amrrs . if you mean fixed as in the column is predetermined, the columns are predetermined yes. and we add new columns to the dataframe by the words from the tdm list

Comment: Are you counting ` ! ` and other punctuation as words or not? Why is "Limited" for the second string at position 12, and why is "Offer" only in position 1?

Comment: @  A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 I have counted the punctuation marks here. Limited is the 12th word. Offer should be at 2 positions 1st and 13

Comment: Posted an answer. There seems to be some mistakes in your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the inputs:

```
tdm <- c('Free', 'New', 'Limited', 'Offer')
subject <- c("Free Free Free! Clear Cover with New Phone",
             "Offer ! Buy New phone and get earphone at 1000. Limited Offer!")
```

I'd do something like:

```
sapply(tolower(tdm), function(x) {
    lapply(strsplit(tolower(subject), "(\\s+)|(?!')(?=[[:punct:]])", perl = TRUE), 
      function(y) {
        y <- y[nzchar(y)]
        toString(grep(x, y))
      })
})
##      free      new limited offer  
## [1,] "1, 2, 3" "8" ""      ""     
## [2,] ""        "4" "12"    "1, 13"
```

What's going on:

- Use `tolower` on both the string to match against and the terms being matched.
- Use `strsplit` to split words and punctuation into separate items in a `list` element.
- Remove any empty vectors with `nzchar()`.
- Use `grep()` to find the location of the matches.
- Use `toString()` to paste the locations together as a comma-separated string.

Comment: Works Well. Thank you. I need a brief explanation again.

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs, No problem. Edited to explain what is happening at each stage.